# Change datetime picker background color

Tags: jquery, css, datetimepicker

I use jquery.pttimeselect.js to create datetime picker. How to change its background? The css I have is jquery.pttimeselect.css, but whatever I do, the background doesn't change. The css is linked corectly. How to change the background color?

Comment: Use a dom inspector to figure out why. Firebug and FF's built-in inspector will tell you exactly what styles are applied to an element, and where the rules came from.

Comment: Chrome has it built-in. Hit F12.

Comment: @Srcee: just right click on the date time picker and select 'Inspect Element' then you will see the matches css rules for that element. And also, you can add your own style and test it on the fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css wan't linked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding the innermost elements (usually DIVs) with these classes:

```
.ui-widget
.ui-widget-content
```

Set the background (not background-color) property to the color of your choice, and see what happens.  If the background is not changed, go up a parent DIV/element and keep trying until you see what you want.  For example, the background of the sample1.html demo (from the ptTimeSelect download) was changed by modifying just 2 rules.

```
#ptTimeSelectCntr .ui-widget{
  padding: .2em;
  background:#900;
}

#ptTimeSelectCntr .ui-widget-content {
  margin-top: .1em;
  margin-bottom: .1em; 
  padding: .2em;    
  background:#900;
}
```

Hope this helps.